# Compile error with boost bind in std::find_if

Tags: boost-bind, c++

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template<typename PODType>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() : m_pred(boost::bind(&SomeClass<PODType>::someMethodA, this, _1))
    {
    }

    bool someMethodA(const PODType& elem)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool someMethodB(const std::vector<PODType>& vec)
    {
        return (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), m_pred(_1)) != vec.end());
    }

private:
    boost::function<bool(PODType)> m_pred;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SomeClass<int> obj;
    std::vector<int> v;
    obj.someMethodB(v);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives

```
error: no match for call to '(boost::function<bool(int)>) (boost::arg<1>&)'
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'boost::arg<1>' to 'int'
```

for the line `return (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), m_pred(_1)));`

I'm trying to call `someMethodA` within the member predicate for the `find_if` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `m_pred`, no need for `m_pred(_1)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering what the syntax in find_if would be, if the m_pred functor would take two arguments. Would it be necessary to bind m_pred then again?

Comment: If you use `sort`, `someMethodA` took two arguments and `m_pred` was of type `boost::function<bool(PODType, PODType)>`, then the call would be `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), m_pred)`, and the member initialization would be `m_pred(boost::bind(&SomeClass::someMethodA, this, _1, _2))`.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to write `&SomeClass<PODType>::someMethodA`, you can just write `&SomeClass::someMethodA`. Within a class template, the name of the class template can be used to refer to the current instantiation.